# Creating a separator in menuitem WPF xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

My xaml looks as below. I have an observablecollection of Menus (called Menulist) which in turn consists of a collection of MenuItems called MenuItems, How can i create a separator style in the xaml

```
  <Menu Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}">
         <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuClick}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding Checkable}" /> 
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
       </Menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this kind of hack (not tested):

```
<Menu Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}">
 <Menu.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuClick}" />
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding Checkable}" /> 
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsSeparator,Converter=hideIfTrue}">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
       </StackPanel>
       <Separator Visibility="{Binding IsSeparator,Converter=showIfTrue}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
  </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

With *showIfTrue* and *hideIfTrue* some **converters** that take a boolean and returns **Visibility.Visible** or **Visibility.Collapse** respectively if the boolean is true.

Comment: Wouldnt the visual tree be set more than once in this case?

Comment: This was the idea: indeed you may need to wrap them in a Grid or another ContentControl.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom Separator Style like below.

```
 <Style x:Key="MySeparatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Border 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        Height="1" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

to use this .

```
 <Menu Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}">
         <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
               .......
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
              <Separator Style={StaticResource MySeparatorStyle}" />
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
       </Menu>
```

Comment: Where would this key be used? in the menuitem setter property? the menuitem setter property doesnot have a separator though